# .htaccess rewrite only if ID exists in database

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a custom blog CMS. Each blog post has an ID in my mySQL database.

Basically I need to rewrite:

```
    domain.com/category.php?id=4
```

to

```
    domain.com/4
```

But I only want this to work if the ID (in this case 4) exists in the database because I don't want every single number to be rewritten.

Can someone tell me how I can get around with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the usual file manipulation functions(fwrite, fopen etc..).

Or you can use `Mod_rewrite` and `PHP`. Check this : http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/